# Масштаб сайта на joomla

Tags: joomla

В общем, если честно, сама не понимаю, где что изменить надо, но опишу ситуацию:

"В настройках браузера масштаб стоит 100%. Все сайты нормально отображаются и сайт, над которым я работаю, на `localhost'е` тоже норм отображался. Ну вот он стал вдруг отображаться по-гигандски."

Где какие настройки надо исправить?

Comment: Ну-у-у, в начале, попробуйтее почистить кэш..

Comment: кэш чистила

Comment: ЖуЖу, здравствуйте! А вам удалось найти ответ на ваш вопрос и решить проблему? Просто у меня то же самое: сайт, сделан на joomla, на бесплатном стандартном шаблоне, когда делала - не обратила внимание, что масштаб моего браузера 90%, все выглядело отлично. Но теперь, когда люди открывают на своих компах его в масштабе 100%, он выглядит каким-то великаном и нарушается его симметричность. Меняют масштаб браузера - все отлично. Вот и думаю, можно ли как-то закрепить за ним масштаб 90%?...

Comment: Это фактически не является ответом на вопрос. Если у Вас есть другие вопросы, Вы можете задать их нажав кнопку "[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)". Дополнительно Вы можете [добавить вознаграждение](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties), чтобы привлечь к вопросу больше внимания, когда Ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет достаточного уровня.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте зажать кнопку **ctrl** и покрутить колесико. Возможно, Вы случайно изменили масштаб таким способом. Такое бывает.

Comment: такой вариант настраивает масштаб в браузере. Я вообще пользуюсь масштабом в 100%, но мой сайт при таком масштабе просто Великан, даже глаза болят переключаться между ним и другими сайтами, т.к. они нормально смотрятся при таком масштабе в браузере

Comment: А после чего так стало? После каких действий? Не видя сайта, тяжело предполагать.

Comment: сама сказать не могу. ДО этого уменьшила сайт как вы сказали ctr+колесико, ну и работала так, а потом на 100% вышла а с сайтом черти что творится. Вот я и решила спросить какие есть варианты, что я могла натворить

Comment: и на этом спасибо

Comment: Если выгрузите сайт куда-нибудь на тест, можно будет посмотреть.